# Jquery UI Resizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some re-sizable divs on my page but I am having issues when I re size them.  The Jquery UI works fine, there is no problem moving them around or re-sizing them, but when  they are re-sized, the div below them acts as if they are no longer present, and it jumps up to their place.  This only happens when they are re-sized though, moving them will not cause this.  Here is a fiddle with my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/367wm/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#header" ).draggable();
    $( "#h-window" ).draggable();
    $( "#p-window1" ).draggable();
    $( "#p-window1" ).resizable();
    $( "#p-window2" ).draggable();
    $( "#p-window2" ).resizable();
    $( "#p-window3" ).draggable();
    $( "#p-window3" ).resizable();
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/367wm/4/**

Basically all I changed was making your divs absolute positioned.  I also added a scroll to your div with all the text in it.

So look for these styles I added to the four divs:

```
style="position:absolute; top:1px;"
style="position:absolute; top:100px; overflow-y:scroll;"
style="position:absolute; top:325px;"
style="position:absolute; top:400px;"
```